# How to use date filter in P4V

Tags: perforce, p4v

I want to filter the Submitted changelist by using the Dates
Is there any way to achieve this?

Its possible in command line using `p4 changes @2011/04/01,@now` but I want it in P4V

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of P4V have good filtering support.  You can open the Submitted changelist view, click the filter section at the top, and adjust to taste.

Comment: I have installed latest P4V Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2013.1/611291 but it doesn't contain the date filter.